# asp.net using jQuery Ajax - Parent page dissapears onClick of a Button in Child page loaded inside the Parent page dynamically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

We are loading a child page in the parent page parent.aspx as follows -

```
$("#result").load("Child.aspx");
```

The Child.aspx consists of an asp:Button.

Problem -
OnClick of asp:Button is causing Child.aspx to be opened instead of being embedded in Parent.aspx as before the click event.

Expected -
Child.aspx should remain embedded in Parent.aspx onClick of the Asp:Button

What we tried: Added an UpdatePanel & ContentTemplate but the Child.aspx page is still getting refreshed.

[Snap1] Parent.aspx:

[image]

Note: onClick of Button will load another page i.e Child.aspx page within the `<div id="result"></div>` of the Parent page itself using

```
 $("#result").load("Child.aspx");
```

[Snap2] Parent.aspx:

[image: Parent.aspx Snap2]

Note: The Child.aspx page gets loaded inside the Parent.aspx page.
The Child.aspx page consists of an Asp.net button named "ChildPageButton".
onClick of ChildPageButton reloads the page and causes the Parent.aspx page to dissapear.

[Snap3] Child.aspx:
[image]

[Snap3]

Code -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Parent.aspx.cs" Inherits="NewLab.Parent" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <title></title>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         function openSection() {
             alert("openSection");
             //Loads the Child.aspx page inside the Parent.aspx result div. 
             $("#result").load("Child.aspx");
         }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:ScriptManager       
            runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <h1>Parent Page</h1>
     <asp:Button ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" Height="51px" Width="218px" />
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                     <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="result"></div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace NewLab
{
    public partial class Parent : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This invokes the javascript function openSection
            if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("openSection"))
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                    "openSection", "openSection();", true);
            }
        }
    }
}



<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Child.aspx.cs" Inherits="NewLab.Child" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function calljs() {

           alert("click");
           event.preventDefault();
       }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div style="background-color:blue; height:400px">
            <h1>CHILD PAGE LOADED!</h1>
        <input type="button" value="htmlbutton" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="AspPageButton"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>**/
```

The code above helps to reproduce the problem.
It can be observed that onClick of ChildPageButton reloads the page and causes the Parent.aspx page to dissapear.
The Child.aspx page appears as an individual page, rather it should remain embedded inside the Parent.aspx page as depicted in Snap2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your child button causes a postback, it's a postback of the child page, so the child page is what gets reloaded. I recommend you consider [ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fb3w5b53%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of JQuery to achieve what you're aiming for here.

Comment: I tried woking with Asp.net User Controls instead of jQuery but did not work out. Will it work with an iFrame?